# Run a python script via import, from another script where parameters are required

Tags: python, bash, import

To launch a python script from terminal, I have to use the following bash commands:

```
python demo_oled_v01.py --display ssd1351 --width 128 --height 128 --interface spi --gpio-data-command 20.
```

Those parameters after `.py` are important, otherwise, the script will run with default settings and in my case, the script will not launch with default settings.

The problem arises when I need to launch my script from another python script, (instead of using bash commands on terminal). To launch one of my python script from a parent script. I wrote into my script:

```
import demo_oled_v01.py --display ssd1351 --width 128 --height 128 --interface spi --gpio-data-command 20
```

in my parent script 
But on terminal, I got an error stating:

```
File "parent_script_v01.py", line 12
import demo_oled_v01.py --display ssd1351 --width 128 --height 128 --interface spi --gpio-data-command 20 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could I get some advice on how I can incorporate these parameters with the `import` module?

Comment: `import`ing a module is different from running the code in the terminal. I suggest you take a look at running your `demo_oled_v01` using the python `Process` module, or take a look at the [`sh` module](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/)

Comment: What if you start your parent script with the same command line parameters instead of adding them to the import statement?

Comment: @ThomasKühn: Thanks for the suggestion. Just tried to do: `python parent_script_v01.py --display ssd1351 --width 128 --height 128 --interface spi --gpio-data-command 20` on terminal but got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want import module to have parameters, You can use python class instead.

I would suggest you should not have multiple entry points in your project i.e.(**main**).

Other way is make your parameters **global**.

Comment: How do I make the parameters global?

Comment: Define a function call it, your code should at least be procedural. 
Or take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python
using this you can define your variables in a different file and manipulate them anywhere.

Can you post a snippet as your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

import does not work with parameters but i can suggest using the os module to call the script. Simply do `os.system("foo.py -parameters")`.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. I originally asked for help in using `subprocess` to launch the script. My understanding is that it is recommended over `os.system`. In that post, someone said that launching a python script from a python script with `subprocess` is quite strange, hence I am trying to use the import module instead.